# A case with generic programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell, generics

Trying to write a simplistic "model-view-controller" app in Haskell (just to learn):

Given the general types `TState` `TAction` `TReaction`,
the key definition is that the function for change the model is

`(TAction, TState) -> (TReaction, TState)` (`:: TFunction_ChangeModel`)

The code to create a function `:: TFunction_ChangeModel` or a function
`:: TFunction_ModelAndViewCombined` is fixed and can be easily generalized (when the necessary functions are provided, see the program below).

I would like (this is the question) to get rid of having to define
dummy types like `type TState = Int` with a note 'please customize'.

Thus,

**can the following code be written without the first three `type Txxxx =` ?**

(Note: any suggestion and criticism is welcome).

```
-- just to make this compile
type TState = Int
type TAction = Char
type TReaction = Double

-- aply an action to an state gives a new state
type TFunction_ChangeState = TState -> TAction -> TState 

-- when a state is entered, a reaction is produced
type TFunction_WhatReaction = TState -> TReaction

-- the model is a function  from an action and a state into a new state and a reaction
type TFunction_ChangeModel =  (TAction, TState) -> (TReaction, TState)

-- given the functions for changing state and finding out what reaction is produced
-- it is straightforward to define the function for change a model
createModelChangeFunction :: TFunction_ChangeState -> TFunction_WhatReaction -> TFunction_ChangeModel
createModelChangeFunction changeState whatReaction = \(ac, st) -> let
        ns = changeState  st ac
        re = whatReaction ns
        in (re, ns)

-- show a view of a transition to a new state and the associated reaction
type TFunction_View = (TReaction, TState) -> IO ()

-- change model and view functions can be easily combined
type TFunction_ModelAndViewCombined = (TAction, TState) -> IO TState

combineModelAndView :: TFunction_ChangeModel -> TFunction_View -> TFunction_ModelAndViewCombined
combineModelAndView change view = \(a, s) -> do
                   let (r, s') = change (a, s)
                   view (r, s')
                   return s'

--
type TFunction_ControllerLoop = TState -> TFunction_ModelAndViewCombined -> IO TState

--
main = do
     print "hi"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to do here - but if you just want to parametrize over  the state, action, reaction... then you can lift those as type-paramters in your types:

```
-- aply an action to an state gives a new state
type TFunction_ChangeState tState tAction = tState -> tAction -> tState 

-- when a state is entered, a reaction is produced
type TFunction_WhatReaction tState tReaction = tState -> tReaction

-- the model is a function  from an action and a state into a new state and a reaction
type TFunction_ChangeModel tState tAction tReaction =  (tAction, tState) -> (tReaction, tState)

-- given the functions for changing state and finding out what reaction is produced
-- it is straightforward to define the function for change a model
createModelChangeFunction :: TFunction_ChangeState tState tAction
                           -> TFunction_WhatReaction tState tReaction
                           -> TFunction_ChangeModel tState tAction tReaction
createModelChangeFunction changeState whatReaction = \(ac, st) -> let
        ns = changeState  st ac
        re = whatReaction ns
        in (re, ns)

-- show a view of a transition to a new state and the associated reaction
type TFunction_View tState tReaction = (tReaction, tState) -> IO ()

-- change model and view functions can be easily combined
type TFunction_ModelAndViewCombined tState tAction = (tAction, tState) -> IO tState

combineModelAndView :: TFunction_ChangeModel tState tAction tReaction
                     -> TFunction_View tState tReaction
                     -> TFunction_ModelAndViewCombined tState tAction
combineModelAndView change view = \(a, s) -> do
                   let (r, s') = change (a, s)
                   view (r, s')
                   return s'

--
type TFunction_ControllerLoop tState tAction =
  tState -> TFunction_ModelAndViewCombined tState tAction -> IO tState
```

I'm not saying that this is beautiful ;)

Comment: Yes, that  could be an option. Thanks. (In C++ I would have defined template functions, depending on the types tAction, tState, tReaction). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to refactor the code to a simpler, readable and usable version using multi param typeclasses in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029455/is-there-a-haskell-equivalent-of-oops-abstract-classes-using-algebraic-data-ty/33128734#33128734)